# Tourist Visa of sweden after applying work permit of dependends

Tags: sweden, application-status

I am working in Sweden on Work permit.I have applied re-union of my family / dependents based on my work permit but it is taking several months to decision come.
Can I apply their tourist visa as well and bring them here for 90 days ?

Comment: I don't process visa applications for a living -- but if I did, I think having a pending application for a family residence permit would count as a big red "overstay risk" flag for a tourist visa. They can apply, of course, but don't be surprised if they're denied. If they can point to a _particular_ reason why they would want to leave after their visit, _and that reason goes beyond_ "of course they'll want to follow the law", the chances are slightly better -- but a planned stay of exactly 90 days seems to count against such reasons existing.